# Javascript - passing array to function, getElementById, not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms, function, getelementbyid

Googled endlessly, going round in circles.

I have a page with three forms on it.
One form offers an advanced search of items and I have javascript operating on the form's select boxes depending on what is selected. The select inputs are hierarchical whereby, if the top level is changed, the select boxes underneath are cleared and then filled by ajax with a new set of options. I am having trouble just getting the **clearoptions** function to work.

So, the form looks like this (I've simplified it):

```
<html>
<body>
<form id="searchform">
    <select id="toplevel" onChange="searchform(this.value,'toplevel',this.form)">
        <option value="option1">Top 1</option>
        <option value="option2">Top 2</option>
        <option value="option3">Top 3</option>
    </select>
    <select id="mediumlevel" onChange="searchform(this.value,'mediumlevel',this.form)">
        <option value="option1">Medium 1</option>
        <option value="option2">Medium 2</option>
        <option value="option3">Medium 3</option>
    </select>
    <select id="lowlevel">
        <option value="option1">Low 1</option>
        <option value="option2">Low 2</option>
        <option value="option3">Low 3</option>
    </select>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The Javascript function that I call when something changes is this below.

```
function searchform(value, changed, theform)
{
    if(changed == "toplevel")
    {
       //clear both mediumlevel and lowlevel boxes if toplevel is changed
       clearoptions(["mediumlevel","lowlevel"],theform);
       return;
    }
    else if (changed == "mediumlevel")        
    {
        // clear just lowlevel box if mediumlevel is changed
        clearoptions(["lowlevel"],theform);
        return;
    }
}
```

And this is the **clearoptions** function that removes the current options in the DOM. I am passing in an array of ids from the **searchform** function and then looping through them to clear more than one select box. The next function after this brings the new options in via ajax but that's not needed here. I need to get this working first.

```
function clearoptions(ids,thisform)
{

    for (i=0; i<ids.length; i++)
    {
        // this is the line where it gives me the error:
        // TypeError: thisform.getElementById is not a function

        var tempid = thisform.getElementById(ids[i]);

        tempid.length = 0;

        var createoption=tempid.createElement('option');
        createoption.text='Include All';
        createoption.value='All';

        tempid.add(createoption,null)
    }
}
```

I just keep getting tempid is not a function errors.

The reason I don't want to hardcode what the form id is in the function is that I have a number of search forms on different pages of the website that are similar and I want to create these functions that I can call from any of them if possible.
Help!

Comment: It is not a function. `getElementById` is a method of `document` only.

Comment: You may have wanted `theform.querySelector`.

Comment: Googling it suggests that's for CSS?

Comment: @TVRV8S I'm just wondering, what you have googled. Probably you haven't found [MDN: querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector)

Answer (score 0):

[document.getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) and [document.createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) are both methods of `document`:

```js
function searchform(value, changed, theform)
{
    if(changed == "toplevel")
    {
       //clear both mediumlevel and lowlevel boxes if toplevel is changed
       clearoptions(["mediumlevel","lowlevel"],theform);
       return;
    }
    else if (changed == "mediumlevel")        
    {
        // clear just lowlevel box if mediumlevel is changed
        clearoptions(["lowlevel"],theform);
        return;
    }
}

function clearoptions(ids,thisform)
{

    for (i=0; i<ids.length; i++)
    {
        // this is the line where it gives me the error:
        // TypeError: thisform.getElementById is not a function

        var tempid = document.getElementById(ids[i]);

        tempid.length = 0;

        var createoption=document.createElement('option');
        createoption.text='Include All';
        createoption.value='All';

        tempid.add(createoption,null)
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<form id="searchform">
    <select id="toplevel" onChange="searchform(this.value,'toplevel',this.form)">
        <option value="option1">Top 1</option>
        <option value="option2">Top 2</option>
        <option value="option3">Top 3</option>
    </select>
    <select id="mediumlevel" onChange="searchform(this.value,'mediumlevel',this.form)">
        <option value="option1">Medium 1</option>
        <option value="option2">Medium 2</option>
        <option value="option3">Medium 3</option>
    </select>
    <select id="lowlevel">
        <option value="option1">Low 1</option>
        <option value="option2">Low 2</option>
        <option value="option3">Low 3</option>
    </select>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Example with input names & multiple forms (note that each form can have a unique id, i.e. form1 and form2, and/or could share a single class, depending on your intent):

```js
function searchform(value, changed, theform)
{
    if(changed == "toplevel")
    {
       //clear both mediumlevel and lowlevel boxes if toplevel is changed
       clearoptions(["mediumlevel","lowlevel"],theform);
       return;
    }
    else if (changed == "mediumlevel")        
    {
        // clear just lowlevel box if mediumlevel is changed
        clearoptions(["lowlevel"],theform);
        return;
    }
}

function clearoptions(ids,thisform)
{

    for (i=0; i<ids.length; i++)
    {
        // this is the line where it gives me the error:
        // TypeError: thisform.getElementById is not a function

        var tempid = thisform[ids[i]];

        tempid.length = 0;

        var createoption=document.createElement('option');
        createoption.text='Include All';
        createoption.value='All';

        tempid.add(createoption,null)
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<form id="form1" class="searchform">
    <select name="toplevel" onChange="searchform(this.value,'toplevel',this.form)">
        <option value="option1">Top 1</option>
        <option value="option2">Top 2</option>
        <option value="option3">Top 3</option>
    </select>
    <select name="mediumlevel" onChange="searchform(this.value,'mediumlevel',this.form)">
        <option value="option1">Medium 1</option>
        <option value="option2">Medium 2</option>
        <option value="option3">Medium 3</option>
    </select>
    <select name="lowlevel">
        <option value="option1">Low 1</option>
        <option value="option2">Low 2</option>
        <option value="option3">Low 3</option>
    </select>
</form>
<form id="form2" class="searchform">
    <select name="toplevel" onChange="searchform(this.value,'toplevel',this.form)">
        <option value="option1">Top 1</option>
        <option value="option2">Top 2</option>
        <option value="option3">Top 3</option>
    </select>
    <select name="mediumlevel" onChange="searchform(this.value,'mediumlevel',this.form)">
        <option value="option1">Medium 1</option>
        <option value="option2">Medium 2</option>
        <option value="option3">Medium 3</option>
    </select>
    <select name="lowlevel">
        <option value="option1">Low 1</option>
        <option value="option2">Low 2</option>
        <option value="option3">Low 3</option>
    </select>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, consider this: As noted, I have 3 forms on my page. 2 of the 3 are refinement options for the current page of search results on a page - one at the top and one at the bottom of the set of results. Both forms use the same IDs for the select boxes: "toplevel", "mediumlevel" and "lowlevel".  The form IDs are "form1" and "form2" so I can select "form2.mediumlevel". The third form is the advanced search form that gives the same options plus many more which, when submitted, goes to a separate search page.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is make functions that can take the form ID and then operate on the same set of select box IDs. There will be three elements with the ID "toplevel" but I should be able to reference the one I want by telling the function I want the child ID of "toplevel" under the form ID of "form2"

Comment: @TVRV8S You cannot have multiple elements with the same id (by definition globally unique).

Comment: Ok, thanks. So there's no way to re-use functions on multiple forms? I wanted to have one set of functions in an included .js file to operate a number of forms on the website as they are fairly similar.

Comment: @TVRV8S You can use the same id only if there's only 1 input on that page with that id. If you have 2+ inputs in different forms, they cannot have the same id. You will need to use classes and names for those.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm a bit of a JS novice. Would you mind posting a quick example of classes and names using my code above, please? I'll of course Google but it's really helpful seeing it in my exact situation.

Comment: @TVRV8S Added an example using names.